# How to prevent window.onhashchange?

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

`window.onhashchange` will be triggered when the event is fired.

Can I ask client whether to change before onhashchange?

Something like `onbeforeunload`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233914/prevent-window-onhashchange-from-executing-when-hash-is-set-via-javascript

Comment: What is currently bound to the event?

Answer (score 0):

You could simulate it. You store the current value of `window.location.hash` in some variable H. In handler for `onhashchange` you pop any alert you want, and then, depending on users response, either save new value to H (if user confirms) or reset it to previous value from H (if user cancels). Did you want such behaviour?

Comment: Maybe. But I dont want window.location.hash been changed. In that case, the page will be rendered and the alert will popup.

Comment: If a user changes it with his hands, you cannot forbid that. But you can remember previous value and immediately change it back. That's what I suggested.